# Turn byte into two-digit hexadecimal number just using ToString?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I can turn a byte into a hexadecimal number like this:

```
myByte.ToString("X")
```

but it will have only one digit if it is less than 0x10. I need it with a leading zero. Is there a format string that makes it possible to do this in a single call to `ToString`?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`myByte.ToString("X2")` I believe.

Comment: Note to self: The 2 in `X2` mean 2 digits. Eg 0A. Where as `X4` would show 000A.

Comment: Also valid: `string.Format("{0:X2}",myByte)`, and since C# 6, `$"{myByte:X2}"`

Comment: Also: the case of the X in the format specifier will affect the case of the resulting hex digits. ie. `255.ToString("X2")` returns `FF`, whereas `255.ToString("x2")` returns `ff`.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you like to do it as below:

```
private static void byte2hex(byte b, StringBuilder buf)
    {
        char[] hexChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        int high = ((b & 0xf0) >> 4);
        int low = (b & 0x0f);
        buf.Append(hexChars[high]);
        buf.Append(hexChars[low]);
    }
```

Comment: How you produce the final result is only limited by the restrictions of the language. However, this is not really a recommended way, however again, it made me grin - in a nice way I will add.  You will need to add ref before StringBuilder in the params for this to work.